# Issue with Remote File Share Server (SAN) path in the XML

Tags: xml, san

I have a XML in App Server which is fetching the path of the Inbox , Processed and Error folder which are also present in the same App Server at E:\

```
<channel name="FundSERV XML File Load for Sales Commission" instance="default" user-id="UVSRTP" password="rtp@uvs" class="com.univeris.rtp.channel.MultiThreadedChannel">
  <task-executor priority="LOW" threads="1" /> 
  <process-trigger sleep-interval="60000" busy-retry="500" /> 
  <heartbeat interval="60000" /> 
  <stalled-check interval="30000" stall-duration="600000" enable="false" /> 
- <channel-schedules>
  <channel-schedule class="com.univeris.rtp.schedules.ChannelScheduleDisabled" /> 
  </channel-schedules>
- <task-manager class="com.univeris.rtpm.esgffs.task.EsgXmlFileLoadTaskManager" product-code="EWMS" entity-code="default">
- <file-types>
  <file-type file-name-descr="WS[PT][a-zA-Z0-9]{7}\.(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\d\d[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\.[AZ](0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)" loader-class="com.univeris.rtpm.esgffs.loaders.v23.SalesCommissionsLoader" xml-parent-node="SalesComms" esg-version="23" fas-type="COM" load-complete-sets-only="true" /> 
  </file-types>
- <file-load-paths>
  <inbox-path>E:\fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\inbox</inbox-path> 
  <processed-path>E:\fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\processed</processed-path> 
  <error-path>E:\fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\error</error-path> 
  </file-load-paths>
  </task-manager>
  </channel>
```

**Now I want to change these paths as follows : 
inbox : `\\SV64050\DLRDEV1-Fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\inbox`
processed : `\\SV64050\DLRDEV1-Fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\processed`
error : `\\SV64050\DLRDEV1-Fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\error`**

**I have modified the XML below shown but files are not getting moved from inbox folder anymore is there any issue with code or some other issue**

```
<inbox-path>\\SV64050\DLRDEV1-Fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\inbox</inbox-path> 
  <processed-path>\\SV64050\DLRDEV1-Fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\processed</processed-path> 
  <error-path>\\SV64050\DLRDEV1-Fundserv-data\esg\SalesComms\error</error-path>
```

Comment: Also these paths are accurate as i have tried to access to these  paths from app server by copying directly from the modified XML file and all the 3 paths were acceesible

Comment: This is not an XML problem. Check your share permissions, run Process Monitor to find out what paths the application tries to access, in short: Debug your application. The XML is fine either way and it is not the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if permissions and locations are ok
so the problem is from the app
some applications cannot take \ .. you should give it a drive
for example X:\abc.... 
so you may make a mapdrives and give them to xml
you can use :

```
net use t: \\SV64050\DLRDEV1-Fundserv-data\esg
```

then change xml like this :

```
<inbox-path>t:\SalesComms\inbox</inbox-path> 
<processed-path>t:\SalesComms\processed</processed-path> 
<error-path>t:\SalesComms\error</error-path>
```